# document library setting

Tags: document-library

I want to set doc lib so that uploader can edit only his file. Basically we have this configurartion setion in advance setting but I am getting in my screen. Can anyone suggest me the same who to see it.

Comment: Can you reformulate? I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You can set the writesecurity on the list through powershell

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity.aspx

Something like this

```
$site = get-spsite http://site
$web = site.openweb("web")
$list = $web.lists["list"]
$list.WriteSecurity = 2
$list.update()
```

Comment: +1, seems the most appropriate answer for the question. At least, for my interpretation of the question -_-. I will edit the question later to be more readable based on my understanding if the original user doesn't clarify his intentions.